# How to Merge two listview of Case object?

Tags: standard-objects, list-view, case-object

I want to merge case object's listview. Where i want to see cases of both listview.

Comment: Hello, You can put conditions for both list view in a single by joining it with `OR`

Comment: Can you explain little more? What is your use case?

Comment: I had two listview for two different users. now i have a situation where my one user is inactive so i need to merge his view to another so that another user can carry forward cases of existing user.

Answer (score 1):

There's no operation to merge list views. You'll need to review the filter criteria of both list views and modify the one you wish to keep to include the criteria of the one you do not wish to keep.